# Mocha not understanding TypeScript "implements" keyword, giving SyntaxError: "... Unexpected token, expected {"

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, babeljs, ts-node, babel-core

I simply want to be able to run Mocha tests in TypeScript with ES6 (I used npm to install mocha, ts-node, and babel-core packages).

My mocha command and the resulting error, followed by relevant code snippets below. Note that ES6 doesn't seem to be the issue here, but the TypeScript "implements" keyword is the problem:

> `$ mocha -r babel-core/register -r ts-node/register model/piece/test/bishoptest.ts`

```
/Users/$USER/projects/chess/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:4454
  var err = new SyntaxError(message);
            ^
SyntaxError: /Users/$USER/projects/chess/model/piece/src/bishop.ts: Unexpected token, expected { (4:28)
  2 | import {PieceHelper} from './piecehelper';
  3 | 
> 4 | export default class Bishop implements Piece {
    |                             ^
```

My code in bishoptest.ts:

```
import { GameState, initialGameState } from '../../gamestate';
import Bishop from '../src/bishop';

import { expect } from 'chai';
import 'mocha';

describe('a bishop test', () => {
  // setup omitted...
  const bishop = new Bishop();
  const res = bishop; // do something (omitted...)
  it('should work', () => {
    expect(res).to.eql(false);
  });
});
```

My code in bishop.ts, where the SyntaxError is occurring:

```
import {Piece, Box} from './piece';
import {PieceHelper} from './piecehelper';

export default class Bishop implements Piece {
  // omitted...
}
```

BTW, here's a bit more information:
At the root folder, where I ran the `mocha` command, I also have a `.babelrc` file:

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

And I also have a `tsconfig.json`, also at the root directory where I invoked `mocha`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6",
        "target": "es6",
        "allowJs": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "**/src/*",
        "**/test/*"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is Piece a class or an interface? Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: Weird! I changed the `class` to `interface` and the `implements` keyword works now with the same below points. Below is the screenshot:

[image]

Notice the different Assertion error messages in the screenshots though! Lol!

If the updated part above suits you then let me know, I will edit the below part accordingly.

---

Instead of the `implements` keyword, I used the `extends` keyword using the same code, with the .ts extensions and typescript installed locally [--save-dev] and used the --compilers switch option for `mocha` like so

```
mocha --compilers ts-node\register bishoptest.ts
```

and it works but I have used the `Piece` as a **class not an interface**. See if it is what you are looking for.

[image]